# How to subset 'n' number of rows past a certain value?

Tags: r, loops, vector, subset, sample

I'm trying to subset a `data.frame` based on a `1` or `0` value the data.frame.

Here is some sample code;

```
> Test
            Close   High    Low    Dn.BB     MaVg    Up.BB      Per.BB Dn.Brk
2007-02-27 6286.1 6434.7 6270.5 6305.813 6389.679 6473.544 -0.11752900      1
2007-02-28 6171.5 6286.1 6166.2 6237.635 6377.186 6516.737 -0.23695539      1
2007-03-01 6116.0 6230.7 6038.9 6164.470 6358.129 6551.787 -0.12514308      1
2007-03-02 6116.2 6164.4 6085.6 6110.807 6341.179 6571.550  0.01170495      0
2007-03-05 6058.7 6116.2 5989.6 6047.421 6318.100 6588.779  0.02083561      0
2007-03-06 6138.5 6138.5 6058.7 6018.953 6297.907 6576.861  0.21427696      0
2007-03-07 6156.5 6167.6 6106.1 6001.139 6278.136 6555.133  0.28043853      0
2007-03-08 6227.7 6233.1 6156.5 5997.989 6264.436 6530.882  0.43106389      0
2007-03-09 6245.2 6255.8 6190.3 6003.152 6250.207 6497.262  0.48986661      0
2007-03-12 6233.3 6276.3 6219.3 6007.297 6237.421 6467.546  0.49104464      0
2007-03-13 6161.2 6240.7 6161.2 6000.401 6223.429 6446.457  0.36049188      0
```

Here, I would like to have something that iterates along the `data.frame` and then splits out the subsets based on `Dn.Brk > 0`. I can only think of a `loop` method here and am not to familiar with `sub-setting`, so was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction / provide some tips of functions / packages that could achive this?

A little more detail below;

```
Sub <- rep(0,nrow(Test))
for (i in nrow(Test)){
    if (Test[i,8] > 0){Sub = Test(i:i+10,1)}
}
```

So, the above would, at every point where `Test[i,8] > 0`, select, `Test$Close` from `i:i+10`.

Ideally, I'd like every sample to be stored in a separate row/column in a new df. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you show your desired output too **for this specific data set**?

Comment: `split(Test, Test$Dn.Brk > 0)` ?

Comment: @Sotos they want some `i:i+10` condition too. And it is not clear what they want to do for reoccurring appearances of `1`s after `0`s

Comment: I assume they mean `Test[i:(i+10)]` instead of `Test[i:i+10]`

Comment: the question is indeed not clear at all ....

Comment: I've adjusted the the `Test` in the code. A desired output for the above would be for the first `> 0`, `Test[1:10,1]`, for the second in Test, this would be `Test[2:11,1]`, the third `Test[3:12,1]` and then the result would be `<0`, so there would be no output. Ideally, I'd like these saved as Rows / Columns in a sample Db - so no overlapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sapply here:

```
sapply(which(Test[, 8] > 0), function(z) Test$Close[z:(z+10)])
```

A few things to note in the loop you provided though:

- You are not iterating: Your loop is from `i in nrow(Test)` which is effectively `nrow(Test)`
- You would be overwriting `Sub` with each iteration

Comment: thank you for the additional knowledge. Is there anyway to split this output into separate rows / columns? For example, if there are 63 points > 0, then the df would contain either 63 rows/columns of this output?

Comment: It is in separate columns for each Test[, 8] > 0

Answer (score 0):

If you are still in search for doing it with a for loop here is the answer:

```
#### results list #####
results <- list()

for (i in rows.test){
if (test[i,8] > 0)
{
  results[[i]] = test$Close[i:(i+10)]
} 
else {results[[i]] = "no value"}
}
```

This could also be further  parallelisable if your dataset is huge with a package called foreach. A good intro here: http://www.vikparuchuri.com/blog/parallel-r-loops-for-windows-and-linux/. You could also change "no value" to next if you want a list with only three named elements